# How can I stream audio from getUserMedia to a server?

Tags: audio, streaming, getusermedia

Is there a way stream audio (using getUserMedia) in realtime from a browser to a server?

I want to know how should I go about implementing it? What kind of data can I take from the browser, so that I can then save it on the server in a file or stream it to other clients from the server in realtime.

I'm pretty much clueless on how to go about this, that's why I couldn't provide any code or more description. Sorry!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out recorder.js:
https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs